# Regular Expression to extract a url included in a string

Tags: php, regex, url

I looked around for a while, but probably I can't "Google" with the proper keywords, so I'm asking here. I need to extract the url from a string, using regexp (php)

A simple example should be helpful:

**Target: extract the url http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kettle**

Base string:

```
/url?q=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kettle&sa=U&ei=VpnIUP22Js3B0gWKhoCgCQ&ved=0CB0QFjAA&usg=AFQjCNGS7-bieZB8Vh7xR5sjOy-KT86ANQ
```

Comment: Do you really **need** to use regex?

Comment: Just FYI, take a look at this tool: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ Really helps testing regex expressions.

Answer (score 4):

There are better options than regex to do this. For instance, PHP provides the two functions `parse_url` and `parse_str` which do exactly what you want:

```
$query = parse_url($string, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($query, $parameters);
$result = $parameters['q'];
```

That is, of course, only unless you need to use regular expressions, because that is all your framework provides or because it's some kind of exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Test this regex: `/q=([^&]+)/i`

```
<?php
  $url = '/url?q=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kettle&sa=U&ei=VpnIUP22Js3B0gWKhoCgCQ&ved=0CB0QFjAA&usg=AFQjCNGS7-bieZB8Vh7xR5sjOy-KT86ANQ';
  $pattern = '/q=([^&]+)/i';
  preg_match($pattern, $url, $res);
  echo $res[1];
?>
```